# Books for Understanding Bayesian probability from the Beginning

Tags: probability, reference-request

Lets pretend I have no experience with statistics...

what books, in what order, will get me to the point of being able to understand  Bayesian probability fastest.

Comment: Do you have experience with probability?  How much?  What do you mean by Bayesian probability?  Almost any probability text will mention some form of Bayes Rule.

Comment: Bayesian _probability_ as in Bayes' rule is described in almost any probability textbook and is noncontroversial even among hard core frequentists (or so I believe). On the other hand, Bayesian _statistics_ and Bayesian _inference_ and the like are a different matter.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The folks at [LessWrong](http://lesswrong.com/) have put together a couple of resources that can be helpful for the complete beginner. They are also useful if you've only taken a single course in probability and basically just memorized formulas to get through it.

- [An Intuitive Explanation of Bayes' Theorem](http://yudkowsky.net/rational/bayes)
- [Bayes' Theorem Illustrated (My Way)](http://lesswrong.com/lw/2b0/bayes_theorem_illustrated_my_way/) (note, this isn't written by me; that's just the title).

For two more advanced books that cover practical matters in great detail (and require a bit more mathematical maturity) see:

- [Bayesian Data Analysis](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/158488388X) by Gelman, Carlin, Rubin, and Stern. (This is a very very good reference for questions on model checking, simulational approaches, and ignorability of experimental designs.)
- [Doing Bayesian Data Analysis](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0123814855) by Kruschke.

My own opinion is that learning the formula for Bayes' theorem is elementary; it's something that almost always precedes even a first introduction to common discrete random variables. The real "starting point" for seeing the difference in Bayesian methods is when you start needing to compute Maximum Likelihood Estimators (MLE). Then you can directly compare the output of an MLE with the alternative output if you had set up a prior and chased the computation out all the way to a posterior distribution.

There's nothing special about MLEs, of course, but that just happens to be one of the first places where a student is really forced to say, "Gee, I'd really like to have the whole posterior distribution, but it's really hard to compute." Once a student sees the value in that, they are usually ready to start learning about acceptance/rejection, Metropolis-Hastings, and Gibbs sampling, which are the gateway drugs of Bayesian analysis.

Answer (score 3):

Reference Book:
[Bayesian Theory by José M. Bernardo and Adrian F. M. Smith](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/047149464X)

Read: [Notes from MIT OCW](http://ocw.mit.edu/high-school/courses/probability-random-isnt-so-random/lecture-notes-and-video/lesson3.pdf)

Presentation: [Tutorial from Stanford](http://robotics.stanford.edu/~koller/BNtut/BNtut.ppt)

Watch videos on Youtube (about Bayesian Probability)

Answer (score 2):

EE, Peter M., 2004. Bayesian Statistics: An Introduction, Hodder Arnold.

Comment: LEE rather then EE

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://bayesianthink.blogspot.com/2012/12/the-best-books-to-learn-probability.html) is a good list. There are lots of material online too, and some excellent q&a right here on stackexchange.