# Pattern Recognition terms a little fuzzy

Tags: conditional-probability, pattern-recognition, bayes-theorem

I've been trying to learn more about probability and the websites I have visited are not describing the relationship to each other that well (when to use what, for what purpose in conjunction with what). I am from a programming background and need to see a clear connection/definition. I am lost in the world of complicated math language at the moment! Could anyone help me understand the following terms in a more simple way?

- Bayes Decision Theory
  This results in a formula (Bayes rule) that can be used to calculate the prior and post probabilities.
- Prior Probability
  This is used to calculate what we expect will happen based on sample data sets.
- Conditional Probability
  When and where is this needed? (In calculations that is)
- Posterior Probability
  After observing events of "today", we can guess tomorrow.
- Discriminant Function
  The function that separates two classes for example (a straight line on a $2D$ graph)
- Gaussian Distribution
  This describes a bell-like shape on a $2D$ graph, for example over a given dataset. How does one confirm if a class of samples are of Gaussian distribution?

I will update the question with relevant information! Any help clarifying these points would be great!

Comment: Your description of [prior probability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prior_probability) is completely wrong, and the others are not correct.  Try a good textbook or at least the Wikipedia pages

Comment: This is exactly why I came here. The wikipedia page is in math/probability langauage. I need to be able to relate the different terms with each other. Any books you recommend?

Comment: Look at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/133230/books-for-understanding-bayesian-probability-from-the-beginning and http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/125/what-is-the-best-introductory-bayesian-statistics-textbook for discussions on books